# Is there a way to filter/sort in separate steps other than using a temporary table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a long running SQL query.

What I have found out that it's faster to compute filters individually than together.

Example :

```
SELECT ...
FROM Foo 
WHERE Cond1 AND Cond2
```

is lot slower (eg : 1 sec vs 2 min) than

```
SELECT ...
INTO Tmp
FROM Foo 
WHERE Cond1

SELECT ...
FROM Foo 
INNER JOIN Tmp ON ...
WHERE Cond2
```

Is there another cleaner way to specify that SQL should perform each filter individually ? (other than using a temporary table as in my example)

---

EDIT:

Somebody asked for more info about tables and queries :

```
SELECT d.IdDocument
FROM Document d
WHERE ((d.IdDocument IN (SELECT ex.RefDocument FROM ExternalKey ex WHERE ex.FieldB = 60))) 

SELECT d.IdDocument
FROM Document d
WHERE
((d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM0)) AND ((d.IdDocument IN (SELECT ex.RefDocument FROM ExternalKey ex WHERE ex.FieldB = 60 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM1))))) OR 
((d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM2)) AND ((d.IdDocument IN (SELECT ex.RefDocument FROM ExternalKey ex WHERE ex.FieldB = 61 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM3))))) OR
((d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM4)) AND ((d.IdDocument IN (SELECT ex.RefDocument FROM ExternalKey ex WHERE ex.FieldB = 62 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM5))))) OR 
((d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM6)) AND ((d.IdDocument IN (SELECT ex.RefDocument FROM ExternalKey ex WHERE ex.FieldB = 59 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM7)))))
```

- Document : 13.000.000 rows. IdDocument is a primary key clustered. There is an index on FieldA.
- External keys : 49.000.000 rows. There is an index on (FieldB, FieldC) that include RefDocument column. RefDocument is a foreign key that refers to IdDocument.

PARAM are temporary tables filled using TVP.

Those two queries are very fast (below one second). However if I combine both WHERE conditions using a AND to have a single query (and adding appropriate parentheses), it runs forever.

What I have tried also is to join the ExternalKey table only once (and getting rid of the "d.IdDocument IN" parts) but it's slow (eg: several minutes of execution)

Eg :

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct d.IdDocument)
FROM Document d
INNER JOIN ExternalKey ex ON ex.RefDocument = d.IdDocument
WHERE (
    (d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM0) AND ex.FieldB = 60 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM1)) OR
    (d.FieldA IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM2) AND ex.FieldB = 61 AND ex.FieldC IN (SELECT Id FROM PARAM3)) OR 
     ...
```

Comment: The stats you are giving us have a context, e.g. how large the tables are, how the queries are being run.  Can you post table structure and the full queries?

Comment: are you using composite indexes? or indexed each field in conditions separately?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : i will add some context

Comment: explain is very good at showing you how you can increase performance on a given query and where the slow parts are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your original examples show `cond1 AND cond2`, it seems your full example shows a lot of `OR` situations. IMHO the `AND` will allow the server to pick the most restrictive one first and start from there, but experience shows that MSSQL doesn't like `OR` very much, nor is it too fond of `IN()` operators, which might be the issue you're really running into.

To work around the `OR` you can use `UNION ALL` (or `UNION` if you expect doubles). To work around the `IN()` you can use `WHERE EXISTS()`.

You'd then get something along the lines of:

```
SELECT d.IdDocument
  FROM Document d
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PARAM0 p0 WHERE p0.id = d.FieldA) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ExternalKey ex JOIN PARAM1 p1 ON p1.id = ex.FieldC WHERE ex.fieldB = 60 AND ex.RefDocument = d.IdDocument)

 UNION ALL

SELECT d.IdDocument
  FROM Document d
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PARAM2 p2 WHERE p2.id = d.FieldA) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ExternalKey ex JOIN PARAM3 p3 ON p3.id = ex.FieldC WHERE ex.fieldB = 60 AND ex.RefDocument = d.IdDocument)

 UNION ALL
 ...
```

PS:I'm also not quite sure how you do `SELECT Id FROM PARAM0` in TSQL? Could it be the problem is because SQL also has problems figuring out what's expected in these 'table-parameters'?

-- UPDATE--

My bad for skimping over the original question. You mention these are TVP's. 
From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters):

> Table-valued parameters can only be indexed to support UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraints. SQL Server does not maintain statistics on table-valued parameters.

I'm guessing having no statistics on these things might make it very difficult for the Optimizer to pick the optimal plan. Dumping them in #temp tables first and adding an index on them before using them isn't an option?

Comment: You are right about the TVP's : they are dumped into temporary tables in order to have statistics. I cannot use a simple WHERE IN (@param1, @param2, ...) because there is too much ID's. Is there a way to dump lot of ID's in temporary tables in C#, without using TVP's ?

About your alternative query with UNION ALL : I will try this out. Btw doing it like that will generate duplicate document ids so i guess I will have to use UNION instead.

Comment: I've played around with creating a uniquely named (GUID) ##table, using SqlBulkCopy to dump values in there and then using that in the query (after indexing the ##table). It works, but requires quite a bit of coding and dynamic SQL. As for the `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`, assuming the number of values returned is _lowish_ it shouldn't be all that much overhead. (I'm assuming those are int's or bigints, so should be fast).

Comment: PS: you probably can get away with 'fixed' #table names too but since I created it all in a helper-stored procedure in dyn-sql I needed to go that route, don't ask =)

Comment: " but experience shows that MSSQL doesn't like OR". I didn't know that. Good point. I tested your solution and performance is s a lot better now. Question : let's say I want to add additional AND filters to a query that already contains several UNION ALL (as in your example). What is the best performance wise ? a) put UNION ALL's between parentheses and add additional query with an INTERSECT operator ? b) add a WHERE condition ? (eg: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION ALL ... UNION ALL ... ) t WHERE condition` c) something else ?

Comment: As with all things in SQL, the only correct answer is 'It depends'. It could well be that both approaches are optimized into the exact same query plan. The only way to know for sure is by simply trying both and looking at what happens. The query plan is a very useful tool to compare different approaches and will give you insight in how MSSQL interprets your query. (I really like "SQL Sentry Plan Explorer" for this). Look for scans where you wouldn't expect them, check if estimated and actual numbers are more or or less in line and do keep in mind that "cost" isn't the same thing as "time". gl.